# Graph QL and DynamoDb update item in array type

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql

I have an schema with:

```
type Profile {
    id: ID
    email : String
    awards: [Award]
}

type Award {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    description: String!
}
```

I need an create a function to update an specific Award with the profile Id and the Award Id, I want to modify title and description in Award.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible insert in specific position:

```
let i = AwardInput['position'];
```

Create Update expression:

```
let expression = "set awards[" + i +"].title = :title, "
    expression = expression + "awards[" + i +"].description = :description, " 
    expression = expression + "awards[" + i +"].initialDate = :initialDate, " 
    expression = expression + "awards[" + i +"].updated_at = :updated_at "
```

Update table:

```
    docClient.update(
      {
        TableName: process.env.USER_TABLE,
        Key: { 'id': AwardInput.id, },
        UpdateExpression: expression,
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                                      ":title": AwardInput['title'],
                                      ":description": AwardInput['description'],
                                      ":initialDate": AwardInput['initialDate'],
                                      ":updated_at":  AwardInput['updated_at'] ,

                                   },
        ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW',
      },
```